# Aeroo Reports неверно обрабатывает поле формата datetime

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Файл-шаблон .odt содержит несколько ссылок на поля, текстовые работают правильно, поле со временем же содержит серьёзную ошибку: время в нём отображается так же, как и хранится в postgresql: в формате UTC вместо UTC+7.
Сайт разработчика этого модуля натолкнул на мысль, что можно прибавить эти 7 часов в самом шаблоне, задав это в директиве наподобие

```
(o.visitdt) + relativedelta(hours=7)
```

но, конечно, так это не работает. Какой должен быть синтаксис, чтобы выполнить подобное? Или же для верного отображения времени нужно cделать что-то другое?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вообще не представляю, что такое odoo. Поле в базе какого типа? Если timestamp with timezone то можно банально пользователю базы таймзону сменить и все таймштампы база будет конвертировать самостоятельно.

Comment: Тип поля timestamp without timezone.

Comment: without timezone читает именно то, что ранее было записано. Так что база тут ничем не поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недостаток информации по допустимым командам для директив шаблонов aeroo reports привёл к тому, что многое пришлось находить вслепую. На вики разработчика есть упоминание временных функций, которые поддерживаются в модуле:

> Time related functions
>
> **dec_to_time** - converts time to hh:min representation;
>
> **time** - time access and conversions;

Среди временных функций есть команда, которая в теории должна решать мою проблему — **tzset()**, но у меня не получилось её применить потому, что шаблон не принимал попытку задать временную зону. Весьма возможно, что я что-то делал не так, но я решил найти иной способ решения проблемы.

Вот он. Метод ужасен, но пока я не придумаю ничего лучше, сойдёт и он.

Я разбил datetime на три части:

```
time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y", time.strptime(str(o.visitdt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

это *дата*, тут всё хорошо,

```
(time.strptime(str(o.visitdt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))[3]+07
```

это *часы*, увеличенные на 7 (мой часовой пояс),

```
time.strftime("%M", time.strptime(str(o.visitdt), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

последняя часть — *минуты* (без изменений).

В результате мы получаем именно то, что хотели (19.10.2017 11:00 для примера).

Очевидно, система будет сбоить, если изначальное время меньше 7 утра, но, поскольку самое раннее время, которое может быть доступно для записи — 8 утра, как временное решение вполне сойдёт.